# Enable 32 bit application Sql Server Connection error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

When I have make below changes in iis8 then sql not connecting.

[image]

After enable getting below network related error.

[image]

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your connection string is saved in registry key. You must create the same registry key with same value under Wow6432 node because 32-bit applications read from this parent node only.

Comment: Thanks. Changes will be done on iis server or database server?

Comment: @AmreshKumarSingh Not on iis or db server. You need to login to the server and run the registry script to create the new key.

Comment: @AmreshKumarSingh please accept my answer if you find it useful